# Can I skip a specific partition when querying an oracle table?

Tags: oracle11g, partitioning

The reason behind this is that I have a known bad partition. I am trying to continue working with the database while the broken partition is fixed by the DBA. There is of course more information available, but I don't know if it is even possible, so I figured I'd start with the question first.

The error I get is `ORA-29954: domain index partition is marked LOADING/FAILED/UNUSABLE`. I know that the right thing to do is to fix the partition, but being just a programmer, I don't have access or skills to do so. All I can do at the moment is attempt to skip over the partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good piece of information on partition pruning. It may help you to alter your queries to avoid the "bad" partition.

http://www.orafaq.com/tuningguide/partition%20prune.html

Other than that, you might have to explicitly reference all partitions to scan and manually omit the bad partition.

Hope this helps,
Ollie

Comment: Thanks for the link, but in reading through it, the only thing that appeared helpful was the suggestions on how to point to the right partitions only. I have a few hundred other partitions that are good, and I'd have to include all of them in my code, so that does not seem like a good solution. Anything else come to mind?

Comment: Not really, I think it really might be a case of going to your DBA and asking them to remediate the bad partition. Do you have permissions to rebuild the index on the bad partition or look into why is has been flagged as bad?

Comment: Yeah, he is working on it, but it may take a few days or more. And in the meantime, we are stuck. I figured I should be able to do SOMETHING. Oh well.